# calling onDestroy in android shutdown

Tags: android, service

If I have a service running in my Android phone and I shutdown, will the service call `onDestroy`? I want the service to perform a task just before the phone shuts down. Although the Google Droid guide says not to put such code in `onDestroy`, I do not know what else can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If `startService()` is called to create your Service you should call `stopService()`, then `onDestroy()` will be called. If you use `bindService()` with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag, than `unbindService()` caused `onDestroy()` automatically. What code they say shouldn't be put there? If it uses this Service of cause `onDestroy()` is not a good idea, if it's something like notification it's ok to put it there.